# Cannot inactivate a subscription in Google Developer Console - the Active/Inactive switch is disabled

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

There is a subscription active for an app in the Google Developer Console and I want to inactivate it. The 'Active/Inactive' link is grayed out and clicking of it in both Chrome and Firefox is futile.

Am I missing something? Is this a transient problem (this is my first foray into subscriptions)? How can the subscription be inactivated on this app? Thanks for your help!

[image: Screen shot of the Developer Console]